# Outlier filter eliminates parts of grid when applying grid_metrics

Tags: lidr, outlier

I need to calculate metrics for a normalized and outliers filtered `LAScatalog`. I am using `grid_metrics` from the `lidR`package in R. The code for filtering outliers is based in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-catalog-apply-examples.html) and, although it seems like it is working, the resulting metrics raster produced lacks some zones of the study area (see Image 1).[image: image 1 metrics with outliers filter applied] The eliminated parts seem to be crops, I suspect that the problem comes up when heights are close to 0.
I applied `grid_metrics` directly to the normalized data to discard errors in the raw data and the resulting metrics covered the missing zones (see Image 2). [image: image 2 metrics without outliers filter applied] 
The script of the outlier filter is the following:

```r
#Basic function detect outliers is to measure the 90th percentile of height in 10 x 10-m pixels (area-based approach) and
#then remove the points that are above the 95th percentile in each pixel plus, for example, 10% (sensitivity = 1.1).
lasfilternoise = function(las, sensitivity)
{
  p90 <- grid_metrics(las, ~quantile(Z, probs = 0.90), 10)
  las <- lasmergespatial(las, p90, "p90")
  las <- lasfilter(las, Z < p90*sensitivity)
  las$p90 <- NULL

  return(las)
}

#Run the previous function for the catalog clusters
lasfilternoise.LAScluster = function(las, sensitivity)
{
  # The function is automatically fed with LAScluster objects
  # Here the input 'las' will a LAScluster

  las <- readLAS(las)                          # Read the LAScluster
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)              # Exit early (see documentation)

  las <- lasfilternoise(las, sensitivity)      # Filter the noise

  las <- lasfilter(las, buffer == 0)           # Don't forget to remove the buffer

  return(las)                                  # Return the filtered point cloud
}

norm <- readLAScatalog("C:/JAIME/dataLAS_test/norm/") #Directory to normalized data

#Options for the catalog engine
opt_filter(norm)       <- "-drop_z_below 0 -keep_first"
opt_chunk_buffer(norm) <- 10
opt_output_files(norm) <- "C:/JAIME/dataLAS_test/norm_p90/{ORIGINALFILENAME}_p90"

options <- list(
  need_output_file = TRUE,    # Throw an error if no output template is provided
  need_buffer = TRUE,         # Throw an error if buffer is 0
  automerge = TRUE)           # Automatically merge the output list (here into a LAScatalog)


#Apply functionto the catalog
output  <- catalog_apply(norm, lasfilternoise.LAScluster, sensitivity = 1.1, .options = options)
ctg_denoised = catalog(unlist(output))
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be sure of the trouble without testing it myself but I'm pretty sure of my answer. I can see two explanations:

#### Weak noise removal function

You filtered the outliers using the example given in this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-catalog-apply-examples.html) but this vignette is not about filtering outliers, it is about building a function that works seamlessly on a `LAS` and `LAScatalog` objects. The vignette is clear on this point.

> We will create a simple `lasfilternoise` function. This example should not be considered as the reference method for filtering noise, but rather as a demonstration to help understand the logic behind the design of `lidR`, and as a full example of how to create a user-defined function that is fully operational.

Your script may be weak because this noise filter function is weak. The noise filter function computes the 95th percentile, add 10% above this threshold and states that all point above are noise. In crops or lakes were all Z are close or equal to 0 in normalized dataset I guess the computed threshold was 0 and you removed all the points.

As a conclusion, read the vignettes for what they are. In this case it is an example of valid function but not an example of noise removal functions. But you can modify the function to improve it.

#### Bad normalization

Also it seems that you have some regions with `Zmax < 0` which is weird. But you used `-drop_z_below 0`. So maybe you didn't not even load any point in these regions. This might be another explanation. Hard to say without more details.

Comment: I think the errors come from the fixed structure of a `catalog_apply`function. exactly in 
`las <- readLAS(las)                          # Read the LAScluster
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)              # Exit early`. Is there a way to change the return value if `las` is empty.  for example 0?

Comment: No it does not. If you think it does, explain why. The code you mention only prevent to enter in subsequent code if you read 0 points.

Comment: You are right, it is not there. The elimination of chunks occurs in the function `lasfilternoise`. I need to make the function change `las`if it is empty. I have tried to include two lines, one goes at the very beggining of it `las0 <- las` and the other right before `return(las)` that goes like `if (is.empty(las)) { las <- las0 }`. I was hoping that if the chunk was empty after the filtering the function would leave the chunk as when is input.